# 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' with Django and scrapy integration

Tags: python, django

I am getting this peculiar error after I try to `runserver` once I have finished web-crawling as my web-crawler is connected to django :

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 107, in check_url_settings
    value = getattr(settings, name)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __getattr__
    val = self._add_script_prefix(val)
  File "/Users/usr/cruises/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 140, in _add_script_prefix
    if value.startswith(("http://", "https://", "/")):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

It seems to be an error located in one of the `django` files rather than from my script. However, I am strongly convinced something in my script is causing this.

Here's my script:

```
from django.db import models
class Cruises(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cruises

def basic(request):
    long_list = Cruises.objects.values('title')
    return render(request, 'cruise_control/basic.html', context = {'long_list':long_list})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.basic, name = 'basic')
]
```

basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cruises</title>
  </head>
<body>
<h1> Cruise Control </h1>

{% for lng_l in long_list %}
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for='destination'>Destination</label>
  <input type="text" list="destination" />
  <datalist id="destination">
  <option>{{lng_l.title}}</option>
  </datalist>
  <!label for="cruisetime">Departure date</label>
  <!input type="date" id="cruisetime" name="cruisetime" min={{dep_l.departureDate}}>
  <!input type="submit">
</form>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I did the following to remove the databases:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
rm db.sqlite3
```

However, the error still occurs.

Turns out the error occurs from this line in my settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

However, this is suppose to create a media folder for me to store images into via

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('cruise_control.urls')),
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I cannot understand why this is throwing an error because it's working on another scrapy+django setup that I have.

Turns out that I needed the following:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Instead, I had

```
MEDIA_URL = []
```

Comment: looks like django is receiving a `list` from you when it's expecting a `str`.

Comment: You should share `basic.html`. It might look like it's Django's, but probably you are passing somewhere `list` object instead of `string` object.

Comment: @NixonSparrow I have deleted my database, and all migrations, then re-installed django so everything should start afresh. After running `python manage.py makemigrations`, I still get the error. I will upload basic.html. I can say for certain this worked some moments ago before.

Comment: @teslajohn why? I don't think it is database-related. I'm pretty sure it has something with your crawler or template.

Comment: Can't help you with that, sorry. But this won't work anyway, because u firstfully get titles instead of `Cruise` objects:

    `long_list = Cruises.objects.values('title')`

Then you try use them as objects:

   `<option>{{lng_l.title}}</option>`

Choose one of them to:

    `long_list = Cruises.objects.all()
    # OR
    <option>{{ lng_l }}</option>`

And don't use same `id` for every object in `for` loop. It's against html rules and it might cause problems. You should use it like:

    `<datalist id="destination_{{ lng_l.id }}">  # assuming you pass objects to template`

Comment: @NixonSparrow I removed all the databases so I could reset the values inputted by the crawler. I have also commented out all files and text relating to urls.py and views.py, but I still get this error. It's likely an issue with the crawler, however I cannot figure out why because the crawler seems to crawl without any issue. Running database migration seems to be the problem

Comment: @teslajohn [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_URL) must be string so, it must be `MEDIA_URL='/media/'`.